# Is it safe trying to get an object for a key that doesn't exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm fairly new to Objective C and there's something which seems to work but makes me uneasy, and that's this.

```
 PFObject *templateObject = [templateObjectId objectForKey:@"GameUnitTemplate"];

    if(templateObject != nil )
    {
```

The point being is that in some versions of the templateObjectId object there is no GameUnitTemplate, it's another class altogether, so is this a safe way of checking whether GameUnitTemplate exists or not?

Comment: yes it is safe to use objectForKey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe, assuming `templateObjectId` is an `NSDictionary` (or sub-class). You'll just get `nil` back. As [documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:):

**Parameters**: `aKey` : The key for which to return the corresponding value.

**Return Value**: The value associated with `aKey`, *or nil if no value is associated with `aKey`*.

Answer (score 1):

If the receiver contains no matching object, it will return `nil`. This is totally safe. Your implementation should test nil as appropriate.

This of course assumes that the receiver responds to `-objectForKey:` (not to be confused with `-valueForKey:`).

Answer (score 0):

If `templateObjectId` is an `NSDictionary` then this is fine--you'll just get `nil` as a result. (If it's not an `NSDictionary` then this might be problematic.)